# XCode13.4 run flutter project failed to build iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I just upgraded to Xcode 13.4 in macOS Monterey 12.4, running a flutter project got this error:

Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-05-21 15:44:37.106 xcodebuild[21400:114339] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **

Now, I am confused, I am running a Flutter iOS app on device, why throughs out errors like watchOS?
And I totally don't know how to resolve this error.
Any one could help me?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Not yet!!!!!!!!

Comment: I've added the steps that solved my problem as an answer. Maybe it could come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

I spent a day to solve this problem.

This worked for me:

Firstly Remove CommandLineTools

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Reinstall CommandLineTools

```
xcode-select --install
```

Select CommandLineTools

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

After

```
cd ios
pod install
pod update

Then clean your project
Rebuild your project
```

My problem was solved with these steps. I don't know if it will work for you, but it's worth a try.

Moreover;
You should check for mac updates. For example, I had notification to install xcode tools.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but it is no work for me

Comment: Fixed, it was my Xcode path configuration problem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe need to upgrade your SDK. try using 2.10.0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32399110)

Comment: It worked for me. I tried a lot of solutions.